# Strange DB-context behaviour when updating collection (Works when stepping through the code in debugger)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a really strange behavior that actually gives me different result if I step through the code using the debugger or just run the app (press play).

The model looks like this;

```
public class QuestionPack
{ 
    public int QuestionPackID { get; set; }
    public string Hashcode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }    
}
```

And I save this class to the DB using a repository-pattern like this;

```
public class EFQuestionPackRepository : IQuestionPackRepository
{

    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<QuestionPack> QuestionsPacks
    {
        get { return context.QuestionPacks; }
    }


    public void SaveQuestionPack(QuestionPack questionpack)
    {
        if (questionpack.QuestionPackID == 0)
        {
            context.QuestionPacks.Add(questionpack);
        }

        else
        {
            QuestionPack dbEntry = context.QuestionPacks.Find(questionpack.QuestionPackID);
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                dbEntry.Hashcode = questionpack.Hashcode;
                dbEntry.Questions = questionpack.Questions; 
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when adding data, but when I try to update (the else statement) I get doubles on the Questions, eg. the questions get saved but with the already saved questions so if i have 4 questions, update that question with *ONE* question and save, i will end up with 9 questions.

BUT; if I step through the code using the debugger (start from the SaveQuestionPack-function and hit "continue", after context.saveChanges()" I get the expected result. I’m so confused I don’t even know where to start looking. 
I guess it have something to do with the fact that I’m trying to store a collection, but why does it work when I step through the save process?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the same instance repeatedly? Data contexts are designed to be created, used, and then discarded or disposed. I'm not sure whether reusing one would give the problem you've seen, but it's a possibility.

Comment: yes, im using the same repository all the time. The result is very conclusive, when stepping through the code it works, when not it dosent work.

Comment: "This works perfectly when adding data, but when I try to update (the else statement) I get doubles on the Questions, eg. the questions get saved but with the already saved questions so if i have 4 questions, add a question and save, i will end up with 9 questions." -- You were talking about updating issue first but later on you showed an example about the issue when adding data. What the hell is the real problem here? Adding data or updating data?

Comment: @Tim: Well stop reusing the context then, to start with. Create a new context in `SaveQuestionPack`, or create a new repository for each request, or something similar.

Comment: Sza, ah, sorry about that. Its when im updating data, but this is done with the "SaveQuestionPack"-function. Will try to write it down better. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Jon Skeet, i tried added; EFDbContext context1 = new EFDbContext(); to the savefunction and saved to that context but ended up with the same result.

Comment: @JonSkeet I manage to solve it, se answear below. Any idea why this would matter?

Comment: @Tim: I suspect that's *effectively* resetting the context's understanding of the data. But that's really just working around the problem instead of fixing it. I'm not an EF expert by any means, but I really think reusing the context across operations is the fundamental issue here.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right, but i did not get it to work with a context in each function either. Its strange, and i really hope i find another solution Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved it but im not really sure why it works...

I added this;

```
dbEntry.Questions.Clear();
```

before;

```
dbEntry.Questions = questionpack.Questions;
```

Anyone having a idea why this corrected the fault?